# How to get the time of last password update for Firebase 9 User?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the [Firebase 9 JavaScript Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) and I want to get the date/time of the last user password update.

Is that possible? And how is it done?

I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any value indicating the last password change timestamp in the relevant Firebase objects that I know of ([User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user), [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential), [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.userinfo), [UserMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usermetadata)). So it seems this information is not available in the API, and you'll need to track it yourself.